# Find the point of inflection

Tags: calculus, self-learning

Will there be an inflection point if there is no solution for $x$ when $f ''(x) = 0$? For example,
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^2-x+1}{x-1}
$$
with domain $\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$

Also, is that when $x$ is smaller than $1$, $f(x)$ is concave down?

Comment: see more with [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%5E2-x%2B1%29%2F%28x-1%29 ]

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669426/applications-of-derivatives-local-maxima-local-minima-and-inflection-point/669518#669518

Answer (score 1):

There is no inflection point if there is no solution for $x$ when $f''(x) = 0$.  For your case, if $x > 1$, then $f''(x) > 0$.  If $x < 1$, then $f''(x) < 0$.

Here is the [double-derivative of $\dfrac{x^2 - x + 1}{x - 1}$ and its graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second%20derivative%20%28x%5E2%20-%20x%20%2b%201%29/%28x%20-%201%29)